# Make a row column text bold after grid has loaded data

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm struggling to find this one now.

After a grid panel's store has loaded, I want to check a couple of things and if certain conditions are met, I want to make the text of a column row bold.

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
Hello      World
```

I'd like to make 'Hello' bold, but I can seem to get my hands on the html of the cell.

I tried, to get the first cell

```
grid.view.getCell(0); //nope
grid.view.getCellByPosition(0); //nope
```

Google is turning plenty of CSS examples, but I'd rather just get the text and replace it with `<b>the text</b>`.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be best to use a [renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) for this.

```
renderer: function(value, metaData) {
   value = value.replace('homer', '<b>homer</b>');
   return value;
}
```

The column renderer receives the value that would be inserted into that columns cell and has a chance to run a function on the value and return the result. So you can add formatting and other useful things. This used to be the method for creating [ActionColumns](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Action) until ExtJs 4 added them to core.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gfs) showing how they can be used.

Comment: Thanks. I know about the renderer, I'm just trying to take a different approach here having to do with two data stores that have to load before.

Comment: The renderer seems to be *the* place to do this kind of thing on a grid. Other options I can think of would be ItemTpl but I think they are mostly used in input fields and the like. Another option would be to iterate the store and change the value, but this could cause some issues if it gets saved back to the DB. I wouldn't approach it any other way I don't think

Comment: @FrancisDucharme, might be worth updating the question with some more infomration about the stores and what you need to do with them.Mention that you are trying not to use the renderer as that will be the first thing that people think of as an answer.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme @Scriptable is correct, a renderer is *the* place for this.  Although you can simply return `return "<b>" + value + "</b>";`  Please explain your situation more clearly so we can try to get the best solution.